# Need to copy columns to new sheet, but certain cells need to be concatenated and cleaned up

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time using VBA and macros in excel, or excel really for that matter. I appreciate any help or insight that you could give me, ranging from what functions to loops can help me succeed in this task

I am trying to get this workbook set up from this:

[Sample Work Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK8pC.png)

I get a list that has to be reordered in order to import into another system. My task list is as follows for a macro:

**Names and companies have to be merged into one, if there is a different name of a person, that must be concatenated. There will not be two different companies per company header.**

**Every File ID per company must be concatenated**

**Individual fees must be replaced with total fee per company.**

**Sorted by internal ID #, A-Z**

**Only one header on the new sheet**

To look like this:
[Target Work Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMQCF.png)

My code below runs this: [Current Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3mp6.png)

```
Sub format()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False




'This is the setup to get rid of unnecessary cells'
 Dim rCell As Range
 Dim cRow As Long, LastRow As Long
 LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 
 '''Delete Merged Cells'''
 With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 Do
 
 Set c = .Find(What:="*Company Name:*", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
 If Not c Is Nothing Then
 cRow = c.Row
 c.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
 Loop While Not c Is Nothing And cRow < LastRow
 End With
 
 '''Delete Headings'''
 With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 Do
 
 Set c = .Find(What:="*File #*", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
 If Not c Is Nothing Then
 cRow = c.Row
 c.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
 Loop While Not c Is Nothing And cRow < LastRow
 End With
 
 
 ''' Delete Sub Total"""
 With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 Do
 
 Set c = .Find(What:="*Sub Total:*", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
 If Not c Is Nothing Then
 cRow = c.Row
 c.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
 Loop While Not c Is Nothing And cRow < LastRow
 End With
 

End Sub
```

Again, I appreciate any help on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Your requirements are vast. I'd suggest outlining which of the requirements you code already does, which it doesn't and which it does but not the way you expect. Also provide more clarity around which parts of your code you need help with.

Comment: Parsing out data arranged in a worksheet like that is a slow and time consuming business. You need to read each cell, row by row, cell by cell, and maintain some kind of state variable that tells you where you are and what each piece of data is for. It's a real PITA. But it looks like you've made a good start. Keep at it and let us know if you have any specific questions

Comment: Thank you all for replying. My code currently removes all of the headers, but has not merged the file ID #'s, names, or totals. Are there any formulas that I can use to merge these file numbers, but not the row itself? If I can figure out how to do that then there should be no problem doing that for the names. For the totals, there are cells with the total but I need to figure out how to transpose this up a row, looking for a value to the left of it. I appreciate the help again and I am sorry for not being clear with my question, as this is my first time on here. Thanks!

Comment: I guess we can assume that there will always be a consistency in the grouping, like the same company name never coming up more than once (grouped). That makes it a lot easier when putting the data together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to loop through the cells.
I picked column `D` with the company name as it didn't have too much clutter.

It's usually good to find the last row, to not loop through cells that we don't need. THere is a lot of ways for doing so as well. Today we'll go with `Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

For the loop, we can use the For next approach, example:

```
For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Range("A" & Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
Next i
```

But this time, I went with the `For Each`, because I think it's a bit more readable.

```
Sub groupingEach()
Dim entry As Variant, prev As String, lRow As Long, lRow2 As Long
Dim inSht As Worksheet, outSht As Worksheet
Set inSht = Sheets(1)
Set outSht = Sheets(2)
lRow = inSht.Range("D" & inSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row            'last row

For Each entry In inSht.Range("D1:D" & lRow)                        'loop 1st sheet
    lRow2 = outSht.Range("D" & outSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row     'last row in output
    If entry = prev And Not entry = "" Then
        '-Group'
        If InStr(outSht.Cells(lRow2, 3), entry.Offset(, 1)) = 0 Then 'does name exist?
            outSht.Cells(lRow2, 3) = outSht.Cells(lRow2, 3) & vbNewLine & entry.Offset(, 1)
        End If
        outSht.Cells(lRow2, 5) = outSht.Cells(lRow2, 5) & vbNewLine & entry.Offset(, -2)
        outSht.Cells(lRow2, 6) = outSht.Cells(lRow2, 6) + entry.Offset(, 2)
    ElseIf Not entry = prev And Not entry = "" And Not entry = "Company" Then
        '-New row
        prev = entry                                    'Save company name for comparison
        outSht.Cells(lRow2 + 1, 1) = entry.Offset(, -3)
        outSht.Cells(lRow2 + 1, 2) = "Payable"          'Where to get this value?
        outSht.Cells(lRow2 + 1, 3) = entry.Offset(, 1)
        outSht.Cells(lRow2 + 1, 4) = entry
        outSht.Cells(lRow2 + 1, 5) = entry.Offset(, -2)
        outSht.Cells(lRow2 + 1, 6) = entry.Offset(, 2)
    End If
Next entry

    outSht.Cells(lRow2 + 3, 1).Value = "Grand Total:"
    outSht.Cells(lRow2 + 3, 2).Formula = "=SUM(F:F)"
End Sub
```

From the examples, this should handle the document all the way from the Sample to the target. I wanted to loop the value copying, but the change in column order made it annoying.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You have no idea how much headache this project has given me. When I run this code in my report the payable is in column A and there is noting in column B. Could you go over with me how I would go to fix this? Thank you again

Comment: Hard to say without looking at it. What happens to the rest of the data? Does your first sheet look like the "Sample" or "current" examples? Is there anything appearing in the other columns in the output sheet?   
The code isn't super dynamic, so it would have to be pretty much exactly this setup.

Comment: Edit: figured out the problem was the offset from the "Payable" column. Completely glossed over that until I ran it with the debug. This works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Oh right, my bad. Forgot to correct that little mistake. Good that you found it. Happy to help.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry to be such a burden but would there be a way to remove the duplicates of the names so that there is just one "Adam Reynolds"? If I need to post it in another question I can. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Ah, another thing I forgot about. That's an easy fix. In the grouping part, we add a check whether the name already exists. We can use the `InStr()` which searches for a string in a string.         `If InStr(outSht.Cells(lRow2, 3), entry.Offset(, 1)) = 0 then` and if it returns 0, the name doesn't exists, and we add it. (I'll edit the code as well)